# How to use stringstream to append in a loop? For example

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I'm trying to use ostringstream to concatenate a string in a loop.  Unfortunately, only the most recent stream is used.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on accomplishing this or similar (other the + with string concatenation)?

Thanks

```
std:ostringstream os;
for (int i = stk.pop(); i != 0; i = stk.pop()) {
    os << i << endl;
}
cout os.str();
```

So the value of 'os' is overwritten every time?  Is there a way to append to the stream?

**SOLUTION**
This code works, I had a bug.

Thanks

Comment: What is `stk`? Apart from missing `<<` in the last line, this code looks correct.

Comment: Did you try to use `std::ios_base::app` as mode?

Comment: Hi, should the last line be `cout << os.str();`

Comment: Needs [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: @Philipp Doesn't need it.

Comment: Your code should append in a loop. What makes you think that it doesn't?

Comment: `cout os.str();` ... missing `<<`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code shouldn't be overwriting `os`. It should be appending to it using the `<<` operator. Perhaps your bug is elsewhere? Maybe your stack only really has the last element?

Comment: This makes a decent comment, but cannot, because the information provided in the question is so limited, provide an answer to the implied question, "Why the <expletive deleted> doesn't my code work?"

Comment: Point taken. We'll have to see -- maybe I'll get lucky and guess his bug. ;-)